# How to get random youtube video in python, discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, youtube, discord

```
    channel = bot.get_channel(901718257864691743)
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({'search_query': message.content})
    htm_content = urllib.request.urlopen(
            'http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
    search_results = re.findall(r'/watch\?v=(.{11})',
                                    htm_content.read().decode())
    await channel.send('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0])
```

How to make this random? Right now it outputs the top result, i'd like to have a little bit of randomness to this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The code above searches for message.content on youtube, and returns 1 video, which is great.. but its always the same video, if the content was the same. Id like to have the video returning be a little more random, so instead of always showing the top result, i could show the top 3, 2, 5, 4 result.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html) , you need to make sure to have '+' incuded in your re.findall() function otherwise it will only return the first result of the output.

so you can try adding '+' in your function like this
`search_results = re.findall(r'/watch\?v=(.{11})+', htm_content.read().decode())`

Comment: You could also try changing `search_results[0]` since you're only checking the first value of the string array. `search_results[1]` would be the second value, `search_results[2]` would be the third value and so on...

Comment: @Eternal Eternus was this of any help?